# Number of routes a Knight can take from xb, yb, to xe,ye on infinite board

Tags: c, recursion

Alright, I have to write a program that calculates the number of routes a knight (on a chessboard) can take to get from (xb, yb) to (xe, ye). Im not sure where Im going wrong. Well I understand that the count wont add anything and will stay 0 in my code, but I also have the feeling Im not too far off either. Im just looking for a push in the right direction. Thanks in advance

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int numRoutes(xb, yb, xe, ye, n){

  int count = 0;

  if(n>0){
      count = count + numRoutes(xb+1, yb+2, xe, ye, n-1);
      count = count + numRoutes(xb+1, yb-2, xe, ye, n-1);
      count = count + numRoutes(xb-1, yb+2, xe, ye, n-1);
      count = count + numRoutes(xb-1, yb-2, xe, ye, n-1);
      count = count + numRoutes(xb+2, yb+1, xe, ye, n-1);
      count = count + numRoutes(xb+2, yb-1, xe, ye, n-1);
      count = count + numRoutes(xb-2, yb+1, xe, ye, n-1);
      count = count + numRoutes(xb-2, yb-1, xe, ye, n-1);
  }
  return count;
}




int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

int xb, xe, yb, ye, n;

printf("Start coordinate: ");
scanf("%d %d", &xb, &yb);

printf("End coordinate: ");
scanf("%d %d", &xe, &ye);

printf("Length: ");
scanf("%d", &n);

int allRoutes = numRoutes(xb, yb, xe, ye, n);

printf("Number of routes: %d\n", allRoutes);

 return 0;   
}
```

Comment: You'll need a mechanism to prevent the knight dodging to and fro between the same two squares, and more broadly, going round in "circles" and repeating an earlier route. Perhaps something similar to the "floodfill" paint routine? Keep track of the squares the knight has already visited.

Comment: Oh and I know this will have a huge runtime when n gets bigger. I know I have to add some limits for when it tries to reach a destination that is further away than the amount of moves it can still take etc, just trying to get the base down.

Comment: Thanks a lot weather vane, I figured it out now! Had to add
      if (n == 0){
        if ((xb == xe) && (yb == ye)){
       return 1;
     }

Answer (score 0):

Here you start from x,y and want to go to tx,ty, with a max length of n.

In a recursive approach your function have to:

- check that it is possible: you need at least Dx+Dy moves (where Dx=ABS(x-tx), Dy=ABS(y-ty), if I'm right, so if n < Dx+Dy no route can be found (return 0)
- check you are on destination point. If yes you have a route (return 1)
- number = 0
- for each possible move (the 8 directions, x+1,y; x-1,y; x+1,y+1…) call yourself with this new x,y, same target, and n-1 (you use a move) and sum the resulting value to number
- return number

If you want to *know* which routes were found you have to manage a global stack and push (x,y) when entering, and pop it when leaving and when finding the target. Moreover when you find the target you should save the route somewhere (content of the stack).

Some improvements:

- have a `visited[N][N]` array initialised to 0 and put 1 each time you push(), put 0 each time you pop(). You can then refuse to test a position which still have been visited for this route (prevent loops, circles…)
- have a check to x,y to prevent visiting elements outside the board
- maybe check for the presence of other stuff on the board (move around other pieces, not "inside" them)

It may look to (without preventing loop, without checking board limits, and with `pstack()` a function that prints content of the stack):

```
int routes(int x, int y, int tx, int ty, int n) {
  int nb = 0;  // number found
  int lng = ABS(x-tx)+ABS(y-ty); // minimal length to reach destination
  if (n < lng) {
    return(0);  // not possible, it will not be a route
  }
  push(x, y);
  // if we are on destination -> 1: we found a route to destination
  if ((x == tx) && (y == ty)) {
    pstack();
    pop();
    return(1);
  }
  // try each move (8 directions)
  nb += routes(x+1, y+0, tx, ty, n-1);
  nb += routes(x+1, y+1, tx, ty, n-1);
  nb += routes(x+1, y-1, tx, ty, n-1);
  nb += routes(x+0, y+1, tx, ty, n-1);
  nb += routes(x+0, y-1, tx, ty, n-1);
  nb += routes(x-1, y+1, tx, ty, n-1);
  nb += routes(x-1, y+0, tx, ty, n-1);
  nb += routes(x-1, y-1, tx, ty, n-1);
  pop();
  return(nb);
}
```

This would give for `routes(4, 4, 5, 5, 2);`:

```
. (4,4) (5,4) (5,5) 
. (4,4) (5,5) 
. (4,4) (4,5) (5,5) 
Found 3 routes from (4,4) to (5,5) with length 2
```